# Función obtenerToken en Laravel consumiendo mi API no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, api

estoy consumiendo un accesstoken desde mi API, al ir a la ruta de prueba y ver su funcionamiento lo hace correctamente, o sea, retorna el $accessToken. Adjunto función:

```
protected function getAccessToken(Client $client)
    {
        $correo = 'token@token2';
        $contraseña = 'tokentoken';

        $response = $client->request('POST', '/auth/login',
        [
            'json'=>
                [
                    'correo' => $correo,
                    'contraseña' => $contraseña,
                    'remember_me'=>true,
                ]
            ]);

        $tokens = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        //$token = $tokens[0]['access_token'];
        $accesToken = $tokens[0]->access_token;
        //dd(accessToken);
        return $accesToken;
   }
```

> Por ejemplo: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjVkMjZiNDhkY2VkZTlmMWYxNzViMzU5NzViNWYwNzAzYjA4MDAwNTc5ODk2YWE4MGIyZGRjZDliNTcwOTBiOGY1OWQzMmM1MmVlYzA2Yjg2In0.eyJhdWQiOiIzIiwianRpIjoiNWQyNmI0OGRjZWRlOWYxZjE3NWIzNTk3NWI1ZjA3MDNiMDgwMDA1Nzk4OTZhYTgwYjJ

Sin embargo, cuando intento llamarla desde mi función index, esto no se realiza y muestra el siguiente error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\Controller::getAccessToken(), 0 passed in
>   /home/Escritorio/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/UserController.php
>   on line 25 and exactly 1 expected

```
public function index(Client $client)
{

    $hola = $this->getAccessToken();
    dd($hola);
    $accessToken = 'Bearer '. $this->getAccessToken();
    dd($accessToken);
    $response = $client->request('GET','/users',
        [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' =>'application/json',
            'Authorization' => $accessToken,
         ]
    ]);

    $users = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

**Cualquier ayuda o aporte sobre mi problemática es bien recibido.**

**Saludos!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltan las variables en el método. Recibe un parámetro de Client, en tu caso **$client**

`$this->getAccessToken($client)`

Comment: Soy un pelotudo, perdóname por favor.
Y gracias! en verdad muchas gracias :D